# How to detect that default launcher app is changed

Tags: android, block, default, android-launcher, android-homebutton

I have developed an app which is working as a launcher app.
When the user removes my app from default launcher I need to know it.

User can remove my app from default launcher in two ways:

`1. Settings->Apps->Reset app preferences.
2. Settings->Apps->My_App->Clear default launcher.`

Please comment if anybody has any idea about:

`1. How I can detect my app is removed from the default launcher?
2. Is there any listener/action for it?
3. Is there any way by which I can restrict/block clearing default launcher?`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What OS is this?

Comment: I have used the Android OS version 6.0 and above device, but not able to detect the event when the launcher is changed from setting in the device.